# Pegar Atributo Data em DIV

Tags: jquery

Em determinada `div` faço um cálculo de área para um site responsivo.

```
<div id="iframe-game" class="help" data-scale="0.8264794383149449">
</div>
```

Pelo jQuery eu tento pegar o valor do atributo `data-scale` assim:

```
$("#iframe-game").data('scale');
$("#iframe-game").attr('data-scale');
$("#iframe-game").prop('data-scale');
```

Já tentei desses três jeitos. Mas não pega. E quando entro no Inspect Element, está lá na `div` igual colei aí em cima.

Eu faço isso no `onLoad`:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
       var percent = $('div#iframe-game').attr('data-scale');
    },1);
});
```

Uso a versão 1.11 do jQuery.

O que eu acredito que esteja acontecendo é que o valor não foi setado ainda e onLoad está sendo mais rápido em carregar... e assim acaba pegando um valor nulo.

Como eu seto o `data-scale`:

```
$('#iframe-game-box').each(function(){

    var iframe = $(this);
    $(window).on('load resize',setViewport);

    function setViewport(){

            var iframeGame = iframe.contents().find("#iframe-game");
            var iframeHeight = iframe.contents().find('body')[0].scrollHeight;
            var iframeWidth = iframeGame.width();
            var windowHeight = $(window).height();
            var windowWidth = $(window).width();

            //Verifica se vai adicionar um valor ao gap
            var heightGap = 0;
            if(iframeHeight > windowHeight){
                heightGap = 70;
            }

            //Verifica se fará a nova escola de acordo com a altura ou largunra
            if(windowWidth > windowHeight){
                var newScale = ((windowHeight - heightGap) * 100 / iframeHeight) / 100;
            }else if(windowHeight > windowWidth){
                var newScale = (windowWidth * 100 / iframeWidth) / 100;
            }

            if(newScale > 1){ newScale = 1; }

            iframeGame.css({
                '-webkit-transform' : 'scale(' + newScale + ')',
                '-moz-transform'    : 'scale(' + newScale + ')',
                '-ms-transform'     : 'scale(' + newScale + ')',
                '-o-transform'      : 'scale(' + newScale + ')',
                'transform'         : 'scale(' + newScale + ')'
            }).attr('data-scale', newScale);
    });
});
```

Comment: Você realmente precisa que seja no `$(window).load()` ? pode acontecer da janela estar carregada e o elemento nem existir ainda, por isso acho q você deveria usar `$(document).ready()`, assim todo html estará pronto quando a função for chamada.

Comment: Se você entrar com a instrução no console: `$('#iframe-game').data('scale');` qual é o resultado?

Comment: @ErlonCharles, tentei isso também. Não foi.

Comment: @KaduAmaral, quando faço isso direto no console, aparece `undefined`.

Comment: E essas: `$('#iframe-game')` e `$('#iframe-game').length`?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cbvxgmmu/ olha isso

Comment: A primeira aparece o elemento, o segundo aparece 0.

Comment: Consegue simular no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Não consigo porquê toda essa parada está dentro de um iFrame. E o cálculo da `div` é feito em outro JS que está fora do iFrame. Mas assim, está funcionando. Porquê o valor é setado na `div`. Só não consigo pegar ele no onLoad, mas se eu chamar dentro de uma função de click por exemplo, pega.

Comment: Como estás a atribuir esse `data-scale`? Já vem com o HTML ou estás a escrever depois?

Comment: Coloquei no Post, @Sergio. Eu obtenho o valor desse parâmetro por um cálculo.

Comment: Diego essa linha `$('#iframe-game-box').each(function(){` é suposto fazer o quê? IDs são unicos então o `each()` não faz sentido aí...

Comment: Se postar o seu código inteiro, por completo com o iFrame e todo o javascript, talvez eu possa entender melhor o porque ele não esta pegando no evento onLoad, provavelmente seja mesmo o problema de carregar antes do valor chegar ao elemento, mas só vendo o código inteiro p/ fazer testes